# How to make multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am new to SignlR using asp.net web api. What i want to do is to make group of admins.

```
[OurAuthorization]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub 
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //if the user is admin add him to the group.which i can access if i have base controller.
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Admins");

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, "Admins");

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
    }
```

The problem is i can not access the current user state (admin or normal user) without an base controller. and i can not now make `NotificationHub`inhert from that controller any other ideas of how can i implement that.
her is the base controller.

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
    {

        public OurIdentity CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                OurIdentity identity = new OurIdentity();
                if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is OurIdentity)
                {
                    identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as OurIdentity;
                }
                return identity;
            }
        }

        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is OurIdentity)
            {
                OurIdentity identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as OurIdentity;
            }
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        }
    }
```

I am using custom token authorization.

Comment: Consider moving that to a static method.  Note that hubs are extremely different from controllers.

Comment: That solved my problem but i fell my logic dose not follow best practice is that right !

Answer (score 0):

in a Hub you can get the Identity via

```
Context.User.Identity
```